# How many stable(infinitely long time) clients connections(sockets) can handle server (boost::asio) on win32 system?

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

Which model is the most suitable servers model for Windows XP?

if the requirements are:
1. c++ ;
2. using async boost:asio ( BOOST_ASIO_HAS_IOCP is set );
3. client indefinitely long time communicates with the server.

How many socket server based on the boost:asio can normally stable process?

Comment: Since `Asio` utilizes the OS IOCP mechanism, the number of connections is only limited by OS capabilities. Actually, the main problem wouldn't be the number of connections, but the number of completion-handlers getting invoked simultaneously.

Comment: Igor, thanks! How to find limits OS capabilities and "the number of completion-handlers getting invoked simultaneously" ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean exactly. As for incoming fully-established connections, there's no any limit, AFAIK. However, there's a limit for half-opened connections (see the following article for example: http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html). Regarding the simultaneous completion-handlers: you'll have to scale your server over multiple CPUs using one of the approaches described in Asio examples.

Answer (score 1):

There really is no single answer that applies to every type of Windows set-up.  You indicated in a comment that you had 64 concurrent connections serviced by a single thread.  That is fine.  In fact, a single thread can service much more than 64 connections - depending on how much work the average message performs.  Many designs involve copying the message to a queue and then having background worker threads process the messages in that queue.  That way the thread with the message handler remains quite responsive.

How many connections can be serviced by a single thread?  That is something that you need to experiment with.  It could be 5,000, 50,000 or even 500,000+.  Same thing for the thread pool that services the queue of messages waiting to be processed.  You need to try different numbers of threads.  The result could be quite different depending on how much cpu time, file or DB I/O is done,  and how modern your hardware is.  Also, keep in mind that there is some significant overhead with threads.  For example, a SO poster some time ago said that a design with 1,000,000 threads was dead on arrival.  That is still probably true today.  So, it is your job to find the number of threads that can most efficiently serve the most connections.

What is the total number of connections that can be achieved with the most modern hardware and a well designed server?  Based on what I have read - 1,000,000+.  If you were doing it with WCF in C#, plan on less than half that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit for connections inside boost::asio. But, there is external limits which can hit you(in order of importance):

- Your app speed and memory usage.
- Thread model and generally your app design.
- Type of connections(SSL or no-SSL). You can run out of memory before
  sockets. On unix i except normal limit 100k for SSL and 1M for
  non-SSL.
- Windows maximum socket limit.

Answer (score 0):

The number of sockets is limited by the OS, although it is large. The main problem you'll run into is the number of parallel processes (threads) that will try to do work simultaneously as they will all fight for CPU time and memory and disk I/O....

Also, a client that lasts a very long time must be written properly so it does not leak anything (memory and whatever other resources.) Otherwise you'll run troubles (especially if you use threads.)

Speaking of memory, creating separate processes for each socket connection is the best way I know of to avoid memory fragmentation.

One last thing, the boost::asio that I know of opens sockets in non-blocking mode and I have not seen a way to change that. It is very difficult to close such a socket properly (i.e. making sure that you read the whole data because you get a close error before the OS sends you the remainder... so you need a full handshake.)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. But I meant the other thing. I'm interested in the most powerful server model on Windows using asio, i.e. multiplexing IO (nonblocking, iopc) + thread( how much thread ). For example, in my last project, I used a model one thread for 64 concurrent connections(i.e. limits winXP, select()). Now, I want to understand better boost:asio library or do not have my old model. What limits will be(asio+win)? And etc.

Comment: "The main problem you'll run into is the number of parallel processes (threads) that will try to do work simultaneously" -- that's exactly what Asio avoids, using *Proactor* (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html)

Comment: @IgorR. If you don't have any parallelism, then you may lose some connections (time outs / starvation). This being said, if the service is expected to return rather small and fast replies, that's not a concern. If it has to compute a lot of things or access complex databases, that's more likely a problem. It really depends on the situation.

Comment: @g3plc, I think that boost asio takes care of that under the hood. You just add signal2 connections while the socket is connected and remove those when the socket gets disconnected. The rest should work automatically. If you have a huge server the limit will be pretty high. If you have a small server (small RAM, poor CPU...) then the limit will be much lower. The best will be to test and see what happens (i.e. have unit tests and such.)